# Please limit the number of PPCG questions which can appear on the HNQ

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Programming Puzzles and Code Golf is a great site, it's fun to take part and there are some super inventive questions and answers.

That said, too much code golf can be a bad thing. And as I write this, there are 10 PPCG questions on the HNQ. Out of 100:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

10% of the HNQ is devoted to a niche site which doesn't really represent what this network is about (Q&A, not puzzles set to the community).

A lot of people here might not browse the HNQ list that often. For anyone on iOS mobile, there is a widget to show you HNQs, and the homepage (Feed) shows them. It's also the homepage of Stack Exchange.

Please add an artificial limit to the HNQ formula to either make it harder for PPCG questions to get on the list, or limit it to (say) 3 on the list. 10% of the list devoted to one site is excessive.