# Limiting a site's appearance rate in Hot Network Questions

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I get that PCG is cool or whatever, but 7/16 seems a bit silly

[image: so much pcg]

Can we flat limit the number of times a Stack appears in HNQ instead of pulling from the list of popular questions without prejudice? I don't care how interesting it is, imo more than two or three from each site gets to be excessive.

(This screenshot was taken from electronics.stackexchange if that makes a difference, which I doubt)

Comment: see also [Please limit the number of PPCG questions which can appear on the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296784/165773)

Comment: it's almost like the number of duplicates may indicate some ***interest in solving this issue***

Comment: it may also indicate that SE team is [not willing to address these issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250154/165773), "...it is quite likely for suggested proposal to stay ignored. It has to be difficult to justify studying and tuning a feature that is designed in a way guaranteeing a negligible impact on a main site in SE network."